# Primefaces Datatable rowindex after using summaryrow

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, summary

I am using primefaces datatable with a  `rowIndexVar="rowIndex"` property for a Sl. No. column used as so :  `value="#{rowIndex+1}"`

I am also using summaryRow where I calculate total hours , sorted by date and employee. I wanted to know if I could start with a fresh rowIndex from 1 after each summaryRow. Right now it goes from 1 till the size of the list,but I want it like ->

```
1  10/03/2015    7:00 am   8:00 am         1 hr
2  10/03/2015    8:30 am   10:00 am        1.5 hr
-------------------------------------------------------
<summaryRow> Total hours worked for 10/03/2015 : 2.5 hr
-------------------------------------------------------

1 11/03/2015     7:00 am   9:00 am        2 hr     
2 11/03/2015     9:05      11:05 am       2 hr
-----------------------------------------------------
<summaryRow> Total hours worked for 11/03/2015 :4 hr
------------------------------------------------------
```

Instead of it being continuously 
1
2
3
4 ..etc

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. This is not possible. Closest you can come is use your own numbers dynamically in model